# Session_End event is not firing

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, session-timeout

I'm trying to call a method which updates a row in a database table in my `Session_End` method.
I've enabled session state in web.config in this way:

```
<sessionState mode="InProc" cookieless="false" timeout="1"/>
```

I've run this and did nothing for more for a minute, but I don't see anything getting updated in the table, hence the `Session_End` method not getting fired.
Any ideas what I could do or why is it not firing?

Here's some sample code

```
protected void Session_End() 
{
    loguseractivity("logout",userip,serverip);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not save anything in the session the Session_End event will not fire. There must be something saved in the session atleast once for the Session_End event to fire

So in Session start below I am saving Hello in the Session_Start

```
protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     Session["Movies"] = "Hello";
}
```

So after session gets over, the session end event will fire

Comment: I use a number of session variables to store different data points, and these are instantiated when the user logs in to the app. Is that not enough?

Comment: Can you send me the settings which you have done in web.config for configuring session

Comment: <forms name="formsauthentication" loginUrl="login.aspx" timeout ="1" slidingExpiration = "true" protection = "ALL" cookieless = "UseCookies" />  <sessionState mode = "Inproc" stateconnectionstring = "tcpip=127.0.0.1:42424" sqlconnectionstring = "datasource=127.0.0.1;Trusted_Connection=yes"; cookieless= "false" timeout = "1"/>

Comment: <system.web>
          <sessionState mode="InProc" />
          .....
     </system.web>

Comment: Do you have this setting also in web.config

Comment: No, this setting is not there in my config file, when i tried giving it its showing me build errors

Comment: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3d39b4/inproc-session-state-mode-in-Asp-Net/  check for adding sessionstate in web.config